# How to check in a Rule of a work item if it has a pull request linked

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to add a new rule to a Task in Agile process template, the idea is to check if the task is closed it must have a pull request link on it. Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a condition to monitor the states changes of workitem:

[image]

But there is no actions built-in to achieve what you want.

If you want to do, you can design your own code to achieve your requirements.